# Launching Google Maps Directions with markers

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

My app needs to open Google Maps directions from A to B eventually more markers like A,B, C, D for driver. Is this possible? If yes, how, can you give some reference, tutorials examples?

Comment: @jackz314 I;ve read it but no one mention how to add more points to the map

Comment: @Henry Well that you handle via the logic of course

Answer (score 0):

Use Map URL, something like this: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters will do the trick.

Depending on your case, refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) for details.

Comment: What about if more points are required, how to add more than two points of route?

Comment: It's mentioned in the documentation, under the section waypoint